# React Props missing validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-props

I have the following "warning" in my code when using props for React. Everything seems to be working fine, however, I have that red underline to my props and when I hover them I have this: is missing in props validationeslintreact/prop-types. Anyone can help me with this, I will appreciate it?

```
export function Order(props) {
  const { id, img, title, description, price } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <div id={`product-id-${id}`}>
        <img
          id={`product-image-${id}`}
          className="product-image"
          src={img}
          alt="This is a product image"
        />
        <h3 className="order-title">${title}</h3>
        <p>${description}</p>
        <p className="price">$ ${price}</p>

        <div>
          <button id={id} className="order-btn">
            Add to Cart
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Everything is working ok, but I am assuming is something wrong with my code

Comment: The warning you are seeing is related to the absence of PropTypes in your React component. You can find some more information about it here: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error/warning seems to be coming from ESLint (the warning title indicates as much).

You can tell ESLint to ignore prop-type linting by adding the following to your `.eslintrc.json` or `.eslintrc.js` file (create the file at your project root if it doesn't already exist):

```json
  "overrides": [
    {
      "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": "off"
      }
    }]
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks to fix the problem, however, do I have to add this to any new React project?

Comment: ESLint is a fantastic tool giving you advice on how to write "clean code".  It comes with a ton of opinions on what is good, bad, and ugly.  For most of those opinions you an either disable ("off"), enable ("on", typically the default), or have it complain to you without error ("warn").  I insist on using ESLint (and Prettier) on all my projects, not just for myself but to also ensure consistency of format and approach across the entire development team.